# Promela: passing array to new proctype

Tags: arrays, promela, spin

I need to pass an array from parent process to child process in *Promela* but it is not allowing me to do so. Also, I have some constraints in making this array global, so can't do this also. How can this be done?

for e.g.:

```cpp
proctype B(int hg)
{
 ..
}

proctype A()
{
    int hg[n];
    run B(hg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`run`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/run.html) says that:

> **DESCRIPTION**  The run operator takes as arguments the name of a
>   previously declared proctype , and a possibly empty list of actual
>   parameters that must match the number and types of the formal
>   parameters of that proctype. [...]
>
> The run operator must pass actual parameter values to the new process,
>   if the proctype declaration specified a non-empty formal parameter
>   list. **Only message channels and instances of the basic data types can
>   be passed as parameters.** **Arrays of variables cannot be passed.**
>
> *[emphasis is mine]*

---

You should consider using **global** variables instead.

In the following example, we enclose the array inside a [*user-defined structured data type*](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/typedef.html) *--together with any other parameter which might be needed by the process--*, and declare a **global** vector of such *Records*. Then, instead of directly passing around the `array` argument, we exchange the `index` of the *Record* containing the parameters for the other process.

```cpp
#define m 10
#define n 10

typedef Record {
    int hg[n];
    // ...
    // other parameters
    // ... 
};

Record data[m];

active proctype A ()
{
    int idx = 1;

    data[idx].hg[0] = 12;

    // ...

    run B(idx);
}

proctype B (int idx)
{
    assert(data[idx].hg[0] == 12);

    data[idx].hg[0] = 17;

    // ...
}
```

This will allow you to generate a verifier:

```
~$ spin -search -bfs test.pml
...
State-vector 424 byte, depth reached 6, errors: 0
...
```

---

**Alternatively**, and *only if you don't need to generate a verifier*, you can simply pass-around your *Record* instance. **e.g.**

```cpp
#define n 10

typedef Record {
    int hg[n];
    // ...
    // other parameters
    // ... 
};

active proctype A ()
{
    Record my_record;

    my_record.hg[0] = 12;

    // ...

    run B(my_record);
}

proctype B (Record data)
{
    assert(data.hg[0] == 12);

    data.hg[0] = 17;

    // ...
}
```

However, this **only** works in simulation mode and in particular it will **not** allow you to generate a verifier:

```
~$ spin -search -bfs test.pml
spin: test.pml:18, Error: hidden array in parameter data
```

In fact, the documentation of [`typedef`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/typedef.html) explicitly mentions that

> A typedef object can also be used as a parameter in a run statement, but in this case **it may not contain any arrays**.
>
> *[emphasis is mine]*

Comment: Thanks for your help but there is yet another issue. If we use array in typedef and then run our file with 'spin my_file.pml', it runs without any error and gives result as desired. But while running our file with 'spin -a my_file.pml' for generating pan file(for verification), it throws an error saying: hidden array in parameter <param_name>

Comment: @Carol thank you for reporting that, I updated the answer.